# Solve Composition of Vector $ {L}_{1} $ Norm and Matrix Nuclear Norm

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization

$$
\underset{A,x}{\text{minimize}} \quad \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{1} + \left\| A \right\|_{*}
$$

$$ D = A + Mx $$

Where $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times z}$, $E=Mx \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times z}$, $n<<m$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times z}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times z}$

Comment: and RCA stands for what exactly?

Comment: You mention $E$, but it doesn't appear in your problem.

Comment: its typo, I mean PCA cause I hope to minimize the rank, and E=Mx.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could solve this using some proximal algorithm such as the Douglas-Rachford method.

Let $C = \{ (A,x) \mid D = A + Mx \}$, and let $I_C$ be the indicator function of $C$:
\begin{equation}
I_C(A,x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } D = A + Mx, \\ \infty & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Your problem can be restated as
\begin{equation}
\text{minimize} \quad \underbrace{\lambda \|x\|_1 + \|A\|_*}_{f(A,x)} + \underbrace{I_C(A,x)}_{g(A,x)}.
\end{equation}
You can use the Douglas-Rachford method to minimize $f + g$.  At each iteration, you will have to evaluate the proximal operators of $f$ and $g$.  Evaluating the prox-operator of $f$ reduces to separately evaluating the prox-operators of the $L_1$ norm and the spectral norm.  The prox-operator of $g$ projects onto $C$, which is a linear algebra problem.

Two good sources to learn about proximal algorithms are the book [Proximal Algorithms](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/prox_algs.html) by Boyd and Parikh, and Vandenberghe's [236c notes](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, happy to know it can be solved. could you help explain: the prox-operator of g projects onto C means?

Comment: @Xia: littleO means that the prox operator of $g$ coincides with orthogonal projection operator unto the convex set $C$. Thanks to the particular structure of $C$, this projection can be computed in closed-form via simple linear algebra. Another good reference for learning proximal methods is P.L. Combettes' http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3522.pdf

Comment: @dohmatob: f(A,x) is easy to separate and evaluate separately, so how about g, how should I evaluate it, and update it?

Comment: @littleO, This is a bit strange. I have never seen a case of ADMM where you have the same variable on the different functions $ f $ and $ g $. What would be the step for updating $ A $? By $ f $ or by $ g $? Or iteratively by both? The way I see it, the problem in its original form is in the ADMM form.

Comment: @Royi Are you familiar with the Douglas-Rachford iteration for minimizing $f(u) + g(u)$? The way I reformuled the problem here fits that pattern. But you are right, it might seem more natural in this case to use the traditional ADMM iteration, as the original problem already has the correct form for that.

Comment: I actually thought ADMM is just like Douglas Rachford. So after I wrote the comment I thought maybe I miss something (Well, I credit you for that :-)). I went to read and so it actually requires them both to have the same set of variables. So it would work.